# Accessing RTP Header in WebRTC (JS)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

I'm trying to access the RTP header stream while in a WebRTC call in JS. I can't find any way to actually do it, so I'm wondering if it's even possible. Does anyone have any insight into this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it is simply not possible with webrtc 1.0